# Failed to resolve: play-services-auth-base-license version 11.8.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, resolve, play-services-auth-base-license

I tried to integrate google smart login and SMS SmsRetrieverClient  in my project. First thing that shocked me is, on the official documentation of these functionalities(https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request#prerequisites), the required libraries are missing. Some how i tried to find out the required ones on net that are :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.8.0'
```

but as i sync the gradle one error is coming. i.e.

> Failed to resolve: play-services-auth-base-license Open File

I have made a lot of search on google but do not got any solution. 
The sample of google on git hub is: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/tree/master/sms-verification/android

Comment: @Manohan Soni try to update your dependencies and make sure you use the latest google-services. if this doesnt help please add your grandle files to help

Comment: @Paraskevas Ntsounos : Actually i am working on our product. So i need to use only 11.8.0. Because all the previous libraries are working with that only. So i can not take risk . I have also used 11.6.0 but with this version the issue is not coming. But i need to fix the issue with version 11.8.0

Comment: check this https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html and also try my answer if you update all libraries everything will work, at least you could try and check if everything works fine.

Comment: Yeh, already integrated in that way... i just found the issue.. it was due to the sequence of jcenter() library. Previously the sequence was                          
   jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven { url 'http://maven.singular.net/' }                                                                       and now i change the sequence and bring the jcenter() down in the last. Some of the libraries are removed from there.... any ways it has been solved. google rocks ---- removed some of the libs from there

Answer (score 10):

i just found the issue.. it was due to the sequence of jcenter() library. Previously the sequence was

> jcenter()
>
> maven { url "maven.google.com"; }
>
> maven { url'maven.singular.net/'; }

and now i change the sequence and bring the jcenter() down in the last. Some of the libraries are removed from there.... any ways it has been solved. google rocks ---- removed some of the libs from there –
So the current sequence is :

> maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
>
> maven { url 'http://maven.singular.net/' }
>
> ```
> jcenter()
> ```

Comment: please next time indicate which file should be edited . for anyone with this problem make the modification in the build.gradle in the android folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your dependencies [based on this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions) like below:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:15.0.1'
```

And make sure that you are using the lateste update of google-services like:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Firebase Android SDKs and Google Play Services libraries [now have independent version numbers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html), allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.
Update the google play service gradle plugin version to latest version (at least 3.3.1).

and update the libraries to the [latest version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Answer (score 0):

in your build.gradle file where you make use of

`compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4+'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'`

replace with

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.23.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'`

Answer (score -1):

If you already have 
`maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`just make sure to move it up before `jcenter()`it will look like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
        jcenter()

 }
```

on `build.gradle(Project:android)`
Oh and I am using `ionic3`.